# When i click on any other button like desi food my order button is triggered

Tags: php, html, button

**when ever i click any other button like desi food fast food or drink my order button is clicked automatically**

i dont know  either button have overlap each other or whats the problem i am a noob

```
 <form method="post" action="orders.php" >
      <div class="container">




      <div class="container col-sm-8">

      <h3 style="color:Purple; text-align: center; background:#A1F3B2; " > Menu: </h3> 
      <div class="container">



        <div class="list-group">

            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#desi">Desi Food</button></a>
            <div id="desi" class="collapse" style="background-color: white;" >
              <input type="checkbox" value="haleem" name=check_list[] /> Haleem <br>
              <input type="checkbox" value="chicken karahi" name=check_list[] /> Chicken Karahi <br>
              <input type="checkbox"  value="chanay paye" name=check_list[] /> Chanay Paye <br>
              <input type="checkbox" value="sabzi" name=check_list[] /> Sabzi <br>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fast">FAST FOOD:</button></a>
             <div id="fast" class="collapse" style="background-color: white;">
              <input type="checkbox"  value="pizza"  name=check_list[] /> Pizza<br>
              <input type="checkbox"  value="burger"name=check_list[] /> Burger<br>
              <input type="checkbox"  value="pizza cone"name=check_list[] /> Pizza Cone <br>
              <input type="checkbox"  value="Shawarma" name=check_list[]/> Shawarma <br>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#drink">DRINKS</button></a>
             <div id="drink" class="collapse" style="background-color: white;" >
              <input type="checkbox" value="coca cola"  name=check_list[]/> Coca Cola<br>
              <input type="checkbox"  value="Red Bull" name=check_list[]/> Red Bull <br>
              <input type="checkbox" value="Orange juice" name=check_list[] /> Orange Juice <br>
              <input type="checkbox"  value="Lemon Juice" name=check_list[]/> Lemon Juice <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>

     <button type="submit"   class="btn-success" style=" display: flex; margin:0 auto; align-items:center;">Order</button>

    </div>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Since the button in HTML5 has default behaviour like `submit`** (according to [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)), you should use `type="button"` on your other `button`s.

Like this:

```html
<button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#drink" type="button">DRINKS</button>
```